# How can I prevent adobe media encoder from trimming the end of the video?

Tags: video

I'm working with videos from a client that need to be converted to Flash from Quicktime.  I've started to encounter a problem where Adobe Media Encoder will trim of a fraction of a second at the very end, which sometimes even clips off the very end of the audio.  The client does not want to add some silence to the end of the videos.

For the complete render settings, please see this screenshot: http://cl.ly/2V372S2N3B0R091N1P1s

Does anyone know what causes this or how it can be prevented?  Adobe doesn't seem to have any information about the problem and Google results all seem to be about intentional trimming.

Answer (score 2):

I can't read your screenshot, and in any case I don't use the particular tool, but I can say that some common reasons for this are: 1) the audio and video are different lengths and the particular encoding scheme or codecs don't like that; 2) the scheme or codec requires that the material ends in a full GOP (encoding quantum).

If these are your issue, possible solutions are obvious: make the streams the same length, and/or pad the streams out to a full quantum. Probably both...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have audio at end without any video?  Try putting in black video until the very end of sequence. (File - New - Black Video)  -- I had an issues when I faded out to nothingness at end and cross fading to black video fixed it.

Additionally, make sure "Source Range" is set to "Entire Sequence" when exporting in Media Encoder.  That could be another problem source.